# android listview of switches, do I need custom adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, simpleadapter, android-switch

I am creating a listview of `Switch` objects, Switch objects contain textview properties, do I need a custom adapter or can I just use a simple adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple adapter has a content view called CheckedTextView. If you need to use a specific view that android pre defined layouts doesn't support then yes, you need to customise it.